# On The Subject of X-Rays

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, nonogram

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of X-Rays

Place the pieces into the grid so that no two pieces touch along an edge, and all uncovered cells are connected. Pieces may be rotated or reflected. Clues outside the grid are nonogram clues.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word is

> **ibex**

Reasoning:

> [image]
>  The first forced move is in the top middle. The top 1 has to participate in a horizontal 2-wide block, otherwise there's no room to fit both 2-wide blocks on that row. So it has to be the L or Z (I'm using these names for both reflections of these pieces). No configuration of the L allows you to complete the rightmost 1-wide blocks (which have to be made from the I and the T). So it has to be the Z, and it has to be reflected.
>  The I and T blocks can be filled in pretty easily, and then if you try to put the O in the top left, you immediately can't fit the L anywhere. Similarly, without reflecting the L you cannot fit the O. The rest is pretty forced.

Next:

> We can read the bottom image as a collection of "not" signs and invert some cells:
>  [image]

Finally, thanks to Gareth McCaughan, we can

> Take the 4 labeled columns and convert them to binary (reading down, grey cells as 1), yielding 9-2-5-24 which is IBEX in A1Z26.

Comment: Now rot13(genafsre pbyhzaf gb gur nopq tevq, artngvat jurer gurer ner abg-fvtaf, vagrecerg nf ovanel, naq qb N1M26). [Comment rather than answer because I think you did the bit that requires actual work and deserve all the credit.]

Comment: Nice! I had done the negation (adding that now). I will do the transformation next. Thanks!! +1